# Getting Magento user session values in joomla

Tags: session, magento, joomla

In my site i have joomla 1.6 and magento 1.5, i would like to get the magento logged user session values in joomla to show as logged in .....

i have tried the following code :

'frontend'));
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
print_r($session);
echo Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getEmail();
echo Mage::helper('customer')->getCustomerName();
?>

But im getting empty values

Note : Sometimes i may get the customer details , if i tried to test the answer like delete the browser cookies and delete cache in magento ,again log in , it results as empty array

Answer (score 0):

It's not that simple. Being logged in implies that there is an associated user account that you are logging in to. You will have all kinds of problems is you have a user register for an account in one system but not the other. What you need is a bridge that syncs the user account across both systems and provides a unified login.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/e-commerce/e-commerce-bridges/9440